# Convert datarow(only single column) to a string list

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, datarow

Please look at what is wrong? I want to convert datarow to a string list.

```
 public List<string> GetEmailList()
    {
        // get DataTable dt from somewhere.
        List<DataRow> drlist = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        List<string> sEmail = new List<string>();
        foreach (object str in drlist)
        {
            sEmail.Add(str.ToString()); // exception
        }
        return sEmail; // Ultimately to get a string list.
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Which column contains your email data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's several problems here, but the biggest one is that you're trying to turn an *entire  row* into a string, when really you should be trying to turn just a *single cell* into a string. You need to reference the first column of that `DataRow`, which you can do with brackets (like an array).

Try something like this instead:

```
public List<string> GetEmailList()
{
    // get DataTable dt from somewhere.
    List<string> sEmail = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        sEmail.Add(row[0].ToString());
    }
    return sEmail; // Ultimately to get a string list.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a one liner I got from ReSharper on how to do this, not sure of the performance implications, just thought I'd share it.

```
List<string> companyProxies = Enumerable.Select(
            vendors.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), vendor => vendor["CompanyName"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the type of `vendors`?

Comment: vendors is an ADO.NET DataSet

Answer (score 7):

Here is how it would be with all additional syntax noise stripped: one-liner.

```
public List<string> GetEmailList()
{
    return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r[0].ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Linq way ...

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dt = getdt();

        var output = dt
            .Rows
            .Cast<DataRow>()
            .ToList();

        // or a CSV line
        var csv = dt
            .Rows
            .Cast<DataRow>()
            .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, dr) => sb.AppendFormat(",{0}", dr[0]))
            .Remove(0, 1);

        Console.WriteLine(csv);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static DataTable getdt()
    {
        var dc = new DataColumn("column1");
        var dt = new DataTable("table1");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
            .AsParallel()
            .Select(i => string.Format("row {0}", i))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(s =>
            {
                var dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[dc] = s;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            });
        return dt;
    }
```